# Como juntar duas linhas em SELECT?

Tags: mysql, select, join

Estou com um problema para juntar 2 linhas. Pesquisei bastante, mas não achei nada que pudesse solucionar o meu caso.

Na query abaixo, há dois SELECT, que retornam duas linhas para cada ramal, conforme imagem abaixo. No código, preciso juntar essas duas linhas para exibir em tela, mas essa junção no código está causando diversos problemas.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso retornar esse resultado em apenas uma linha? Por exemplo:

|2016-04-15|2200|Bruna Farias da Silva Neves|1|454|18|470|

Obs.: Preciso agrupar por data e por ramal.

```
   ( SELECT     date(cdr.calldate) as data, 
            cdr.dst as ramal, 
            users.name as nome, 
            count(date(cdr.calldate)) as qtde_entrante, 
            sum(cdr.duration) as tempo_entrante, 
            NULL as qtde_sainte, 
            NULL as tempo_sainte 
    FROM (`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`) 
        JOIN `asterisk`.`users` ON `users`.`extension` = `cdr`.`dst` 
    WHERE cdr.calldate >= '2016-04-15 00:00:00' 
    and cdr.calldate <='2016-04-15 23:59:59' 
    AND cdr.dst LIKE '220%' 
    GROUP BY date(cdr.calldate), cdr.dst) 
 UNION ALL 
 ( SELECT   date(cdr.calldate) as data, 
            cdr.src as ramal, 
            users.name as nome, 
            NULL as qtde_entrante, 
            NULL as tempo_entrante, 
            count(date(cdr.calldate)) as qtde_sainte, 
            sum(cdr.duration) as tempo_sainte 
    FROM (`asteriskcdrdb`.`cdr`) 
        JOIN `asterisk`.`users` ON `users`.`extension` = `cdr`.`src` 
    WHERE cdr.calldate >= '2016-04-15 00:00:00' 
    and cdr.calldate <='2016-04-15 23:59:59' 
    AND cdr.src LIKE '220%' 
    AND cdr.dst not in ('s') 
    AND cdr.dst not like '*2%' 
    AND (cdr.dst < 900 OR cdr.dst > 999) 
    GROUP BY date(cdr.calldate), cdr.src) 
    ORDER BY date(data) asc, ramal asc)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: procure sobre group_concat, mas cuidado que pode deixar um pouco mais lento, mas pode te ajudar

Comment: Olá Marcelo. Eu encontrei esta função, mas não consegui aplicá-la no meu exemplo :(

Comment: Ola, Não consegui perceber o que pretende. Consegue colocar um exemplo http://sqlfiddle.com/. Para conseguir ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

É possível fazer isso com SQL, mas vai acabar enfrentando problema de lentidão.

Em código, a solução sem problema de performance é levantar os dados de entrada e de saída separadamente, levantar todos os ramais de pessoas que tiveram ligações nesses dias e fazer o JOIN manualmente.

O SQL abaixo tenta replicar esses passos.

```
SELECT A.data
     , B.extension
     , B.name
     , C.qtde_entrante
     , C.tempo_entrante
     , D.qtde_sainte
     , D.tempo_sainte
FROM   ( SELECT DISTINCT DATE(calldate) AS data
         FROM   cdr
         WHERE  calldate BETWEEN '2016-04-15 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-15 23:59:59'
       ) AS A
CROSS JOIN
       ( SELECT extension , name
         FROM users
         WHERE extension IN ( SELECT src FROM cdr where calldate BETWEEN '2016-04-15 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-15 23:59:59' )
          OR   extension IN ( SELECT dst FROM cdr where calldate BETWEEN '2016-04-15 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-15 23:59:59' )
       ) AS B
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT date(calldate) as data
              , dst as ramal
              , count(date(calldate)) as qtde_entrante
              , sum(duration) as tempo_entrante
         FROM   cdr
         WHERE  calldate BETWEEN '2016-04-15 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-15 23:59:59'
          AND   dst LIKE '220%'
         GROUP BY 1,2
       ) AS C ON ( A.data = C.data AND B.extension = C.ramal )
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT date(calldate) as data
              , src as ramal
              , count(date(calldate)) as qtde_sainte
              , sum(duration) as tempo_sainte
         FROM   cdr
         WHERE  calldate BETWEEN '2016-04-15 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-15 23:59:59'
          AND   src LIKE '220%'
          AND   dst not in ('s')
          AND   dst not like '*2%'
          AND   (dst < 900 OR dst > 999)
         GROUP BY 1,2
       ) AS D ON ( A.data = D.data AND B.extension = D.ramal )
WHERE ( NOT qtde_entrante IS NULL ) AND ( NOT qtde_sainte IS NULL )
```

Comment: Isso deve funcionar para o caso que ele precisa.

Answer (score 2):

## Separe em duas sub-consultas

Sua pergunta está incompleta para fazer mais testes porém acredito que o caminho é você criar duas sub-consultas e depois juntar com os usuários. Um `SELECT` que represente as chamadas de entrada (onde o ramal está ligado ao campo `dst`) e outro que represente chamadas de saída (onde o ramal está ligado ao campo `src`).

Pelo entendimento da sua saída, essas consultas deveriam ser juntadas pela data e pelo ramal, ou seja, onde tanto a data como o número do ramal tem registros de chamada de entrada e saída. Depois de juntar essas duas "views" você faria a junção com a tabela de usuários usando o campo `extension`.

Eu entendo que podem haver chamadas de entrada em datas que não tem chamadas de saída e vice-versa, então o `JOIN` poderia ser um `FULL OUTER JOIN`, porém é preciso analisar se você quer pegar essas situações no seu resultado. No caso de um *outer join* você também precisará fazer a ligação com a tabela de usuários duas vezes, uma para o `dst` e outra para o `src`.

Como ilustração (porque não tenho como testar) a consulta abaixo poderá te ajudar a entender o que estou propondo e fazer adaptações necessárias para o resultado final.

Como dica sobre problemas de desempenho, é provável que isso tenha a ver com o `LIKE`. Tente remodelar a base para que permita esses filtros de forma a usar expressões simples (`=, >, <`)

```
SELECT 
    date(entrada.calldate) as data, 
    entrada.ramal,
    users.name as nome,  
    entrada.qtde_e, 
    entrada.duracao_e, 
    saida.qtde_s, 
    saida.duracao_s
FROM
    (
        SELECT  cdr.src as ramal,
                cdr.calldate,
                COUNT(cdr.calldate) qtde_s,
                SUM(cdr.duration) as duracao_s
        FROM asteriskcdrdb.cdr AS cdr
        WHERE cdr.calldate >= '2016-04-15 00:00:00' 
        and cdr.calldate <= '2016-04-15 23:59:59' 
        AND cdr.src LIKE '220%' 
        AND cdr.dst not in ('s') 
        AND cdr.dst not like '*2%' 
        AND (cdr.dst < 900 OR cdr.dst > 999) 
        GROUP BY cdr.calldate, cdr.src
    ) AS saida
JOIN
    (
        select  cdr.dst as ramal,
                cdr.calldate,
                count(cdr.calldate) as qtde_e, 
                sum(cdr.duration) as tempo_e
        FROM asteriskcdrdb.cdr as cdr
        WHERE cdr.calldate >= '2016-04-15 00:00:00' 
        and cdr.calldate <= '2016-04-15 23:59:59' 
        AND cdr.dst LIKE '220%' 
        GROUP BY cdr.calldate, cdr.dst
    ) AS entrada
ON entrada.ramal = saida.ramal 
AND entrada.calldate = saida.calldate
JOIN asterisk.users as users ON users.extension = entrada.ramal
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SELECT DISTINCT. A função ja filtra o campo que realizara o select, acredito que remontando a sua quero usando ele possa facilitar. https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187831(v=sql.105).aspx;

Answer (score 1):

Olá, talvez possa abandonar o UNION e tentar selects que resolvam os counts para você dentro da consulta inicial, por exemplo:

```
SELECT     date(cdr.calldate) as data, 
            cdr.dst as ramal, 
            users.name as nome, 
            count(date(cdr.calldate)) as qtde_entrante, 
            sum(cdr.duration) as tempo_entrante, 
            (SELECT COUNT(date(cdr.calldate)) FROM asteriskcdrdb.cdr WHERE [..outros filtros..]) as qtde_sainte, 
            (SELECT COUNT(cdr.duration) FROM asteriskcdrdb.cdr WHERE [.. outros filtros..]) as tempo_sainte 
    FROM (asteriskcdrdb.cdr) 
        JOIN asterisk.users ON users.extension = cdr.dst 
    WHERE cdr.calldate >= '2016-04-15 00:00:00' 
    and cdr.calldate <='2016-04-15 23:59:59' 
    AND cdr.dst LIKE '220%' 
    GROUP BY date(cdr.calldate), cdr.dst)
```